# What are the "method names" in hub connections?

Tags: signalr

I've scoured through the .NET documentation and cannot find what these strings representing methods mean. For instance "ReceiveMessage" and "SendMessage" in:

```
hubConnection = new HubConnectionBuilder();
...
hubConnection.On<string, string>("ReceiveMessage", ..);
```

and

```
await hubConnection.SendAsync("SendMessage", userInput, messageInput);
```

are some examples. I realize in the Hub we have methods that can be these names, but sometimes not? For the toy example I'm using from the .NET documentation, a ChatHub class is defined as follows:

```
public class ChatHub : Hub
{
    public async Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
    {
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("ReceiveMessage", user, message);
    }
}
```

So here I can see the "SendMesage" method exists. But nowhere is there any "ReceiveMessage" method in the source code. I'm a bit disappointed the documentation doesn't actually explain what these strings representing functions mean in any detail. Do they represent javascript functions? Only locally defined functions in C# (then where is ReceiveMessage?)? Globally defined functions in SignalR? What are they?

Answer (score 1):

They refer to methods on the client.

I guess the exact details vary between languages, but here is one simple example in Dart/Flutter using the [signalr_netcore](https://pub.dev/packages/signalr_netcore) package:

**In your server code**

```
// Call the TestMethod method on the client
await Clients.Caller.SendAsync("TestMethod", "some arguments from the server");
```

**In your client code**

```
hub.on('TestMethod', (arguments) async {
  print('TestMethod called from server with $arguments');
});
```

The above code will print `TestMethod called from server with [some arguments from the server]`.

Comment: Thanks. I'm just trying to wrap my head a bit why strings are used and not static typing which would take advantage of compile time checking. From what I gather this design decision would lead to runtime errors that could have been caught at compile time. I notice also that the client seems to call actual methods via the SendAsync function, however when it registers to an "event" via the hub.on method, it's essentially creating the method itself via a lambda. One advantage I can see doing things this way is dynamic function names generated at runtime. Is that the reason its like this?

Comment: JavaScript isn't statically typed :).  You can use strongly typed hubs on the server side though https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubs?view=aspnetcore-7.0#strongly-typed-hubs-3